# Rails 4 doen't show stars jquery-raty-rails gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, raty

I have installed jquery-raty-rails gem. Into my view.haml I have:

```
%p Averate rating
#star
```

Into other view .erb I have this code (I render this view inside which one have #star )

> ```
> $('#star').raty({
>   readOnly: true,
>   score: 2
> });
> ```

But no way. I cannot see the stars. I have tried multiple ways to do that, but it was impossible. This code give me the next error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. I am getting crazy!

Comment: have you added js to application.js ?? //= require jquery.raty

Answer (score 0):

That was happened because I added a jquery.js from a template which I bought and  I had jquery gem installed too. It seems to have a conflict between those two files!

Thanks for you answer Sahil!